# my windows xp pc can't open executable files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd.exe

My windows XP SP3 media edition PC can't open some .exe files. I get a message saying

> for Windows to open this program it must know who created it. This includes mmc.exe, device manager and other Windows files along with some but not all downloads.

### Addendum:

I went into folder options and unchecked *"hide extensions for known file types"*. I also unchecked *"do not show hidden files and folders"*. No help.

Earlier today I tried to restore my PC but got *"unable to open rstrui.exe"*. However if I go into system32 and click on `rstrui.exe` it takes right off.

Also, if I open system in control panel and try to open device manager I get the "can't open" message, but if I type devmgmt.msc into run, it opens right up! I checked folder options again and exe files are associated with apps as normal. Please help!

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a potential issue with file extensions. You should double-check the extension by unhiding common extensions if you haven't already done so (and I would double-check that as well).

Comment: please do proper writing and format the post to make it readable. Moreover each punctuation must "stick" with the word that accompanies it, leaving a space on the other side. And lastly, don't use win XP